# AngularJS 1.3.0 no longer shows default selection when ng-options references different model from select ng-model

Tags: angularjs

My form `select` and `ng-options` worked perfectly fine on AngularJS 1.2.26, always showing the default selection if `toy.toy_container_name` was available in the `containers` array. However, after upgrading to 1.3.0, the select dropdown no longer shows the default selection (same behavior in Chrome, FF, and Safari so not browser issue). My Selenium test caught this, and now I'm baffled as to why. 1.3.0 does not appear to have any deprecations or noticeable changes (from 1.2.6) that could result in this issue. Furthermore,

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="toy.toy_container_name" ng-options="c.container_name as c.container_name for c in containers" required>
        <option value="">- Pick Container -</option>
</select>
```

Further making this confounding is the inspection of the source show the correct selection; however, the  dropdown select box does not show the selected default:

Chrome Elements Inspector:

```
<option value="" class="">- Pick Container -</option>
<option value="0">A-BIN</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">B-BIN</option>
<option value="2">F-BIN</option>
<option value="3">G-BIN</option>
```

**EDIT: I found the issue:**

Why would moving '$scope.toy = toy;' after fetching for containers make a difference in the new Angular 1.3.0?

```
$http({method: 'GET', url:'/toys/'+$stateParams.id}).success(function(toy, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.original = angular.copy(toy);
        //$scope.toy = toy; // WORKED in AngularJS 1.2.26 but not 1.3.0

        $http({method: 'GET', url:'/containers'}).success(function(containers, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.toy = toy; // moved from where previously commented; NOW works with AngularJS 1.3.0
            $scope.containers =  containers;
        }).error(errorMessage.onError);

}).error(errorMessage.onError);
```

Comment: Able to replicate it here? http://plnkr.co/edit/6GpDcNR792kLL0peEzrk?p=info

Comment: @tasseKATT see updated problem with code updates that rectified the issue. I'm still trying to figure out why this would cause the issue.... any thoughts?

Comment: I was able to replicate the situation. It works in 1.3.0-rc.5, but not in 1.3.0, so must be something in the recent release.

Comment: Thanks @tasseKATT for further researching... sounds like an issue that needs to be reported to the AngularJS team. If you post the issue to the Github project, let me know the link so I subscribe and watch... thanks for your help again.

Comment: Tested on 1.3.2 and still doesn't work....

Comment: And tested on 1.3.3, still doesn't work... I'll try to create plnkr or similar and submit a bug report.

Comment: What doesn't work if plunker works? Tried with 1.3.4 and 1.3.0

Comment: I forked the original plunker to show the error: http://plnkr.co/edit/7nBZLR8siWn1cfck9LIH?p=preview  - Is there an issue open for this on angular's github?  I feel like this should be happening to a lot of apps

Comment: sounds like it should be fixed in 1.3.5: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9714

Comment: or not... still doesn't work in 1.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is a known bug in the 1.3x branch. Please see here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11835

Select controller does not realise that the options have changed - must force render manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wait for a response from the server and then render the DOM, look:

```
<div ng-if='toy'>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="toy.toy_container_name" ng-options="c.container_name as c.container_name for c in containers" required>
        <option value="">- Pick Container -</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

(not `toy`, not `render`)

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you should make use of ng-init to show the default value on load.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-init="<value you want as default>" ng-model="toy.toy_container_name" ng-options="c.container_name as c.container_name for c in containers" required>
    <option value="">- Pick Container -</option>
</select>
```